# divergence rate- how slow it can be?

Tags: calculus

Sorry that I have been bothered with these questions lately. Suppose I know that n/p(n)^a goes to zero, for some a>0, as n goes to infinity. This obviously requires p(n) to diverge. But how slow it can be? If p(n)~n^b for some b>0, then a exists. If p(n)~log(n), can we find such a? My guess is no. Then it brings to my question- how slow the divergence rate of p(n) can be?

Comment: Do you really mean $a > 0$?  You example of $p(n) \sim \log(n)$ is trivially dismissed when $0<a<1$.

Comment: Extremely sorry, Eric. The original version is not clear. I have edited it.

Comment: Relevant: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/588527/13130) *AND* [How did Rudin conclude his argument there is no "boundary" between convergent and divergent series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234661/13130) *AND* [Boundary for Series That Converge "Fast Enough"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023658/13130) *AND* [Finding a sequence which $\to 0$ "fast enough"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457014/13130) *AND* [this 10 September 1999 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/wgU-JCpiTJk/m/dwCLo8No0y0J).